# App Launcher Disappears after using Portal site connection SharePoint 2016

Tags: applauncher

This appears to be a bug.  Without any branding applied and using SharePoint 2016 On-Prem, when I enable the Portal site Connection on a Team site, the App Launch bar disappears and I don't see any breadcrumb to get to the Portal site.

Bismarck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this issue. I've added a Portal Site connection on a Team site to another Site Collection within the same Web Application (just a Publishing site in my case) and the Suite Nav is still present.

Comment: OK, but where is it?  I don't see the portal connection after enabling it.